# Pass large data using jquery.ajax

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am using asp.net and jQuery 1.6

In my function I am required to pass html tags as a data parameter to my server side method written in C#. In my Database the column has Blob datatype.
I am able to submit data successfully upto 528b but If I submit large data... I'm not able to send at server side.

When I pass small data it works and a row inserted. But If I pass data around 17Kb then this doesn't go to the sever side, but prompt me an undefined error in jquery.

Following is Ajax Code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Post.aspx/savePost",
    data: "{Title:'" + Title + "',Html:'" + Html + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data == undefined) {
            alert("Error : 219");
        }
        else {
            alert(data.d);
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        if (data == undefined) {
            alert("Error : 465");
        }
        else {
            alert("Error : 468 " + data.d);
        }
    }
});
```

Following is C# code

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string savePost(string Title,string Html)
{
    string retMsg = "Not Saved";
    Post bp = new Post();
    int count = 0;
    count = bp.mySavePost(Title,Html);
    if (count > 0)
    {
        retMsg = "Post Save Successfully.";
    }
    return retMsg;
}

protected int mySavePost(string Title, string Html)
{
    int count=0;
    try
    {
        string rawQuery = "INSERT INTO temp_posts (Title,HTML)"
                        + " VALUES(?Title,?HTML)";
        cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = rawQuery;
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?Title", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Title;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?Html", MySqlDbType.Blob).Value = Html;
        count = c.insertData(cmd);
     }
     catch(Exception ex){}
 }
```

Please guide me with you valuable knowledge.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, could you try to inspect the error in Firebug or Chrome Dev tools depending on which browser you normally use? It would be interesting to see whether the request is actually being sent to the server and what's the exact response.

Comment: You can use fiddler to debug your requests.

Comment: Dear Juri and Jupaol thanks to join this thread.
The request is going to server when I'm passing a small amount of data.

Comment: Passing with large data request doesn't reach to server but prompt an error. I'm not able to debug. But when pass the small content then I can debug and it works successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many Thanks to everyone who put his best effort for this thread.

Finally with the help of one my senior I found where I was lacking in my code.

As I am passing html tags as a data parameter to my server side method written in C# from `jQuery.ajax();` I need to encode the data.

As I used the `escape()` function in javascript to encode it worked. Data is submitted to database.

```
var encodedHTML = escape(Html);         //here encoding Html.
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",   
    url: "Post.aspx/savePost",  
    data: "{Title:'" + Title + "',Html:'" + encodedHTML + "'}",  
    contentType: "application/json",  
    dataType: "json",  
    success: function (data) {  
        if (data == undefined) {  
            alert("Error : 219");  
        }  
        else {  
            alert(data.d);  
        }  
    },  
    error: function (data) {  
        if (data == undefined) {  
            alert("Error : 465");  
        }  
        else {  
            alert("Error : 468 " + data.d);  
        }  
    }  
});
```

Thanks everyone :)